# Rails: User has_many :recommendations :through other users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a rails project where users have_many :recommendations. A user also has_many followers and following through connections:

```
 has_many :recommendations
 has_many :followers, :class_name => 'Connection', :foreign_key => 'user_id'
 has_many :following, :class_name => 'Connection', :foreign_key => 'follower_id'
```

When a user creates a recommendation, their followers should be able to access that recommendation.

So I'd like to be able to call following_user.following.recommendations to get recommendations from *all* the people that user is following.

What's the railsy way to do this with ActiveRecord?

Comment: Just to add to br3nt's answer. Take a look at the documentation for associations. Has many through is what you need http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the association you want to use in the through via the `source` option.  Just pass it the name of the association on the other class.

The [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference) explain the `source` option like this:

> The `:source` option specifies the source association name for a `has_many :through` association. You only need to use this option if the name of the source association cannot be automatically inferred from the association name.

Something like this should work:

```
class User
  has_many :followed_users, :through => :following, :source => :user class_name: User

  has_many :followed_recommendations, :through => :followed_users, :source => :recommendations, class_name: Recommendation
end
```